# Using specific child components with a generic parent component

Tags: reactjs

Maybe I'm thinking about this in the wrong way, as I've only just recently picked up ReactJS, so feel free to correct my method of thinking.

What I want to do is (theoretically) be able to have N specific child components that can fit into a single parent component, but I'm not sure how to tell the parent which child to render.

For example, I've written a tab container that just renders a content area right now. The content area would be the `parent`. I want to have N different types of items that can go into this content area. These items would be the `children`.

Is it possible for me to use a single parent component and someone dynamically chooses which type of child to render without going through the hassle of a conditional statement in the parent?

Let me know if my question is not clear.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes do this like so:

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return React.DOM.div({}, this.props.childClass(this.props.childProps));
  }
});
```

or:

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return React.DOM.div({children: this.props.children});
  }
});

Parent({}, ChildClass({foo: 'asdf'}))
```